# Mail only the checked check boxes

Tags: php

I am trying to write a script that will allow me to include only those check boxes that were selected by the user and then mail them to me to respective email address .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$message = "<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=utf-8' />
<title>Something</title>
</head>
<body>


    <strong>Name</strong> : $name <br />
    PHONE : $phone <br />
    Company : $company<br />
    Selected options:<br />" .

 (isset($_POST['cb2']) ? 'Add me to your email list for updates<br>' : '') . 
 (isset($_POST['cb3']) ? 'Contact me regarding partnership<br>' : '') . 
 (isset($_POST['cb4']) ? 'Others<br>' : '') .
 (!isset($_POST['cb1'] &&
  !isset($_POST['cb2'] &&
  !isset($_POST['cb3'] &&
  !isset($_POST['cb4'] ? "None selected<br>" : "") .
    "Comments/Questions:<br />
    <hr />
    $mess
    <br />

</body>
</html>";
```

Comment: one last question suppose if none are being checked by the user then what should i write in the code that sends none are selected????

Answer (score 0):

Only selected checkboxes are sent by the browser anyway. So have something like the following:

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value of checkbox one" name="check[]"> Label for checkbox one</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value of checkbox two" name="check[]"> Label for checkbox two</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value of checkbox three" name="check[]"> Label for checkbox three</label>
    <label><input type="checkbox" value="Value of checkbox four" name="check[]"> Label for checkbox four</label>

    <button type="submit">Go</button>
</form>
```

And then in PHP, `$_POST["check"]` will contain an array of all selected values.